# Gerar menu e submenu com PHP

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3

**Situação:**

Estou construindo um menu com submenu de informações que recupero do banco de dados, estes dados são categorias e subcategorias de produtos, este menu esta pronto e funcionando porém quando não há subcategorias (que é um submenu do menu) esta gerando uma `<ul>` vazia.

**Tecnologias envolvidas:**

- CakePHP 3.0 que recupera os dados do banco através de seu ORM. (julgo pouco impactante no problema).
- Templates padrão do CakePHP com extensão `.ctp`.
- PHP usado para renderizar o menu e submenu.

**SQL das tabelas categoria e subcategoria**

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE sub_categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  sub_category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY category_key (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

**Template que gera o menu e submenu**

```
<div id="left-sidebar" class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#"> <?= $category ?>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($subCategories as $subCategory): ?>
                    <?php if($subCategory['category']['category_name'] == $category): ?>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="#"> <?= $subCategory['sub_category_name'] ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**OBS** `$categories` é um array de string simples e `$subCategories` é um array de objetos (que possui como uma de suas propriedades um objeto que representa uma categoria onde uma propriedade deste objeto e o nome da categoria).

**Foto do menu e submenu** (o problema de acentuação é devido a collation do mysql, mudarei posteriormente).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Menu renderizado no browser**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#"> Alimentos<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#"> Industrilizado</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#"> In natura</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#"> Comida pronta</a>
            </li>
        </ul>                                                                                                                                                                                      </ul>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#"> Bazar<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Falta-te um `if` de verificação se existem subcategorias:

```
  <?php if(/*existem subcategorias*/){ ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($subCategories as $subCategory): ?>
                <?php if($subCategory['category']['category_name'] == $category): ?>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="#"> <?= $subCategory['sub_category_name'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

A `<ul>` vai aparecer sempre, se não queres nenhuma tens de verificar antes da `<ul>` se existem subcategorias.

Answer (score -3):

Como bem disse o Jorge, você tem de ter um if antes do `<ul>`.

Algo como isto:

```
<div id="left-sidebar" class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#"> <?= $category ?>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

           <?php if($subCategories): ?> ///////verifica se a variável está vazia////////
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($subCategories as $subCategory): ?>
                    <?php if($subCategory['category']['category_name'] == $category): ?>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="#"> <?= $subCategory['sub_category_name'] ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
          <?php endif; ?>////fim do if////
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).